# Yii Captcha Extension

Tags: yii, captcha

I am using great extension Extended Captcha from

[www.yiiframework.com/extension/captcha-extended](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/captcha-extended/)

I did everything as it is described. After replacing original Captcha with Extended one in Contact form, it worked fine.  Now I am trying to implement it into registration. The only difference is that I try to save the `$model` :

```
    if($model->validate() && $model->save()){
         ...
    }
```

I have an error of captcha validation, when actually `$model->validate` returns `true`

I have tried to remove saving, and just try to validate:

```
    if($model->validate()){
         ...
    }
```

Worked fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Solved. The problem was that after `$model->validate()` the captcha value is changed somehow, that's why the second `validate()` which is in `$model->save()`, returned `false`

Answer (score 0):

What value is returned from method "save" ? 
If you overwrite this method, then You must return boolean value from it, or return parent::save($params, $attrs).

Comment: I did not overwrite save() method, but only beforeSave(), in which I return parent::beforeSave()